# How many live users at the same time on website. CPU/memory/brandwidth

Tags: html, server, cpu, ram

(hypothetical scenario)

I will host a very simple static one page html website.
It will only have a simple text similar to "Hello world" and a button that redirects to another website (~2kb).

The "hello world" website will be hosted from my computer with node.js.
My question is.. How many "live" users would be possible to handle. Meaning people who just sit on the website and refresh every ~30 seconds. Let's say ~30000 people who refresh. Meaning the website will have ~1000 refreshes per second. This process will be active in ~3 hours.
What factors are responsible here?
My CPU? RAM? Bandwidth?

(hypothetical setup)

100/10mb stable fiber connection with top router.

16gb RAM.

i7-2600k 3.4GHz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what your Hello World application is doing. If it's solving differential equations for your users, it'll use a lot of CPU. If it's functioning as a streaming movie server, bandwidth and memory usage will be significant. The hello world app below was tested with the Apache benchmarker on a dual core VM with ~2GB ram to get a rough idea what one might expect.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write('<p>Hello World</p>');
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

As you can see, this program is very basic, running with no frameworks and no logic. Either of those will change these results significantly. The `-n` param is the number of total requests in the test, and the `-c` param showed the number per second.

```
ab -n 30000 -c 1000 <URL>
```

Note that the Document Length is 18 bytes. Any increase there will scale your bandwidth linearly (so if you have a 1kB html file, you'll be looking at roughly 1kB * 1000/sec = ~8mbps bandwidth, around 80% of your upstream link). For this reason, caching is very important. While processing 1000 requests per second, node used 99% of the CPU (as the 1000 concurrent connections likely saturated its ability to respond and it thus always had something to do). One of the benefits of node, however, is that it uses relatively little memory for high-concurrency, so it hovered at around 3% memory usage of the 2GB available.

```
Document Path:          /
Document Length:        18 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   5.355 seconds
Complete requests:      30000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      3540000 bytes
HTML transferred:       540000 bytes
Requests per second:    5602.75 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       178.484 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.178 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          645.63 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

Hopefully this is helpful when designing your application!

Comment: Thank you! It is very helpfull. I will do a similar test when I have the time. If you are interested in the results I will post the results bellow.

Comment: I'm always interested in results! What did your hello world actually look like?

Answer (score 0):

Lets calculate a bit:
1000 refreshes/second * 2kByte = 2MByte/second => 16MBit/second + a bit overhead for the requests => ~ 20MBit

So your 10MBit connection will be a bit too slow, but 100MBit would be more than sufficient in this case.

I don't think RAM or CPU power will be a problem, if you only have a static page.

But I should add, that I don't really have experience with that.

Comment: Thank you! I will updrage to 100mbs in upspeed to be safe!